# Reset input dialog when user press cancel and saving input to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI which will take a user input as text for a given range. What I have done so far is getting a QInputDialog to get user inputs. But the problem is whenever i click cancel it just goes to next input. I want to reset the fields and start over. Also I want to add these inputs to a list when a user is done.

Here is my code:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.le = QLabel()
        self.le.move(30, 62)
        self.le.resize(400,22)
        self.le.setText("")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 160, 160, 80))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 150))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))



    def showDialog(self):
        num, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Setup', 'How many rooms in the house?:')

        for i in range(num+1):
            name, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Setup', 'room{}:'.format(i+1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()  
    ui = Example()  
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)  
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not to use for-loop but a while-loop where the index increases when the user presses the ok button:

```
def showDialog(self):
    names = []
    num, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(
        self, "Setup", "How many rooms in the house?:"
    )
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        name, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
            self, "Setup", "room{}:".format(i + 1)
        )
        if ok:
            i += 1
            names.append(name)
    print(names)
```